# How can I set up a passwordless non-privileged account?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, password

On my Xubuntu 20.04 system there are two users - me (strong password, with sudo) and my daughter (no sudo access).

Her account can be set to log in without a password, but that's not much use when the screensaver kicks in as it then demands the password to unlock (that I was forced to set but no one can remember because it's never used - and of course she doesn't have access to my password manager).  And if I try to set a blank password the account won't enable.

[image]
[image]

Note that there are several related questions, but all refer to remote login or sole/privileged users, and giving a passwordless user root access dominates the answers. I also don't want to recreate the old guest login that doesn't have a permanent home folder. So how can I have a kid's account without a password?

Comment: Do not set the OS to ask for a password when coming back from screen saver.

Answer (score 1):

If open the powermanager in your settings (or click on the power icon on your panel -> select "PowerManager settings..") make sure to disable the "Lock screen .."  checkbox:

[image: 1]

Then open the "screensaver" and disable the lock screen:

[image: 2]

**Enable lock screen** needs to be turned off.

**Update**

To disable the password on login (terminal):

`sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

and add below the "Seat" section:

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=<user>
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

and replace <user> with the user name

Comment: I would rather the account actually didn't have a password, as opposed to having one that didn't get used, but this does seem to be the easiest way

Comment: See my updated answer on how to "disable" the password